Quicker way to retrieve Amazon orders from SP API
We're currently using Amazon SP API to retrieve a scheduled GET_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_INVOICING report every 15 minutes. That report contains all orders fulfilled by ourselves. Problem is that the report generation seems to be delayed on the Amazon side. They take 2 or 3 times (30 or 45 minutes) to contain a purchased order.
This delay is limiting our own time frame for fulfilling the order. Worst case would be Amazon devalues our whole seller account, due to delayed fulfillment.
If I recall right I could retrieve orders per OrdersV0Api API, not per reports. But the results of getOrders calls are missing some important invoice fields.
Anyone has a suggestion on how to retrieve orders in a more real-time approach?

That's one of the biggest problem we actually face as well, as a lot of customer are requiring us to retrieve orders faster. Unfortunately there is no better way, as far as I know, to handle this. It is true that some fields are missing from the Orders API, and this is a block for a complete switch to Orders API. But it is also has to be noted that there is a particular timeframe where a placed order, can still be canceled by the user. In fact, Orders API will let you get also orders in PendingAvailability / Pending status.
This is - but this is my opinion - the reason that causes reports to seem "slower": they contain only valid and ready to be shipped orders.
In conclusion, I would stick with Reports API, considering that probably this will be probably replaced in the near future with Data Kiosk. Otherwise, you can think about a hybrid approach (like use Orders API to start blocking your inventory and start preparing packs that you can fulfill as soon as you have a valid and confirmed order).

Thanks for shedding some light here. I totally forgot about that pending state. I will try to find out if the fulfillment timeframe depends on the state in some way - it should, but that's just my opinion.

did u find a solution? What is the best way to retrieving the orders fastest and lively updated? I'm building an inventory management system so orders will be connected with the inventories it is important to lively updated. I was thinking using the notifications but I've realised that it doesn't give the new order notifications I guess. Should I fetch reports in every morning then continue on the orders en point or what? Thank you.

This isn't an answer. Maybe you meant to leave a comment instead?
